# iframe stops javascript from working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with an iframe on a website that i'm building of the adminLTE template (based on bootstrap)
You can find an example version of this template here: http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/

When i include an iframe in a blank page, all the animated controls stop working (like the collapsing charts, UI elements, forms buttons on the example page)
As soon as i place an iframe tag with a src in it (on line 405 of the code on the example page below) it stops responding.

In terms of code: everything is mostly like in the template, on this page: http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/pages/examples/blank.html

The differences with my code are:
- i do not have the small settings widget to the right
- i don't load the demo.js
- im using asp.net with a setup where everything is in a master page, and the content is everything from line 389 to line 409

Let me know if i should explain anything else in more detail.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you please setup a fiddle

Comment: i´m also using this panel once with lots of iframes in content, so your problem is another

Comment: its trocky to setup a fiddle because there is alot of code involved, but the code is really exactly the same as http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/pages/examples/blank.html
but if i add <iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" /> on line 405 it stops working

Comment: when i insert <iframe src="stackoverflow.com"; />  in element inspector on the example page in content 405, the example page keeps on working so i cant reproduce it and youre error is another one, what console errors do you have

Comment: Thanks!!!! when looking at the console output i found:

HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.
File: test.aspx, Line: 373, Column: 13

i was closing the iframe with />, and when i replaced it with a </iframe> tag, it worked.

I'm a bit of a noob in webdevelopment, does it show? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was self-closing the iframe (`<iframe />`) while i should have closed it with `</iframe>`

I found this by following john Smith's advice to go and check the console output.